# my-little-pony and friendship-is-magic

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

15 questions tagged [my-little-pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony)
15 questions tagged [friendship-is-magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friendship-is-magic)
Exactly the same questions.

What's the difference between these two tags? Should they be merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the discussion here, I've renamed [friendship-is-magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friendship-is-magic) to [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim), and setup a synonym from the former to the latter.

Comment: there are still two separate tags?

Comment: @Solemnity Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure, [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/what-was-star-swirl-the-beardeds-spell-supposed-to-do).

Comment: @Solemnity Yes, we still have a franchise tag, and a series tag.  See also [tag:star-trek] and [tag:star-trek-ds9].

Answer (score 5):

I think we should change [friendship-is-magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friendship-is-magic) to [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim).  *My Little Pony* (MLP) is a long running franchise with many series under that banner.  *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* (MLP: FiM) is simply the latest of these.  It's conceivable we'll get MLP questions that aren't FiM questions (admittedly I'm not familiar with previous incarnations, so I can't speak to whether or not there are good questions to be had from them), but all FiM questions are necessarily MLP questions.

So deleting either one and creating a synonym would prevent proper tagging should there be non-FiM MLP questions in the future.  It's similar to the family of [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) or [stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate) where the various series have their own tags, then there's also the franchise tag.  We just don't have the same wealth of fandom here for the other *My Little Pony* series that we do for the various *Star Treks* and *Stargates*, so the MLP tags' overlap leads to a terrible Venn diagram of 100% overlap.

Comment: The difference to e.g. [tag:star-trek] is, that there actually exist [tag:star-trek-tng] and [tag:star-trek-tos] (and more) questions.

Comment: I guess I'd recommend then making a [tag:my-little-pony-fim] and setting [tag:friendship-is-magic] as a synonym.  Leave the existing [tag:my-little-pony] tag as is.

Comment: I've updated my answer to align with my new stance.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest solution would be to change [friendship-is-magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friendship-is-magic) to [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim). By using [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim), the My Little Pony questions are still easily identified, and we can eliminate having to use two tags to make up for a length limitation. For those 15 questions, they don't need a [my-little-pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony) tag, because they're just about the show Friendship is Magic. If there are questions just about MLP beyond the scope of the current show, then [my-little-pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony) would be applicable.

This change would be congruous to [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)/[star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9), so the precedence is there.

Edited to reflect Pureferret's suggestion for easier identification.

Comment: I'd prefer, [tag:My-Little-Pony-FIM], as a tag.

Comment: FiM is less widely accepted than MLP. It'd be more recognized.

Comment: Agreed, but a) it follows the [tag:star-trek]/[tag:star-trek-ds9] line of abbreviating the more specialised series, and b) people familiar with MLP will recognise FIM as well, but those not familiar will at least know what the main universe is.

Comment: Ok. I see that idea.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless whether there are additional series in that universe, there are no questions *here*. This tag clutter doesn't help anyone. Since the tags always coincide, and 15 questions is a decent amount of variance, I'd vote to merge the tags into [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim) (as suggested by Kevin and [Gabe Willard](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1767/2565)) and leave the old tags as symlinks.

Comment: The maximum tag length is 25 characters, too long for [tag:my-little-pony-friendship-is-magic]. Should the main tag be [tag:my-little-pony] or [tag:friendship-is-magic]? Or should we just delete one of the two and not make a synonym?

Comment: @Gilles That tag length limitation was why I used two tags for some MLP question I had a while back.

Comment: We use abbreviations for other series, e.g. star-trek-ds9, so how about my-little-pony-fim

Comment: @Kevin: That sounds reasonable. I'll edit.

Comment: Thats effectively identical to my suggestion...

Comment: But it's different enough I think.