# Remove tag [my-little-pony]

Tags: support, tags

Science Fiction and Fantasy.

First, some facts.  As of this writing, our site has about 30 questions about (My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic(, all of which are [tagged with [my-little-pony-fim]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim) and about 25 of which are [tagged [my-little-pony]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony).  We don't seem to have any questions about My Little Pony before the Friendship is Magic reboot.  (No surprise, for Friendship is Magic is what made the franchise really popular.)  Using two tags is confusing, and something should be done.

<del>Here's what I propose.  I ask the admins to remove the [my-little-pony] tag from all questions.  If any new questions remain untagged from this, tag those questions with [my-little-pony-fim] if they are about the Friendship is Magic universe, or with [my-little-pony] if they are about previous generations.  At the same time, modify the [my-little-pony] tag wiki to say something like:</del>

> <del>*My Little Pony* franchise of Hasbro before the *Friendship is Magic* reboot in 2010.  For questions about *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic*, please use the tag [my-little-pony-fim] instead.</del>

A previous tagging question on meta about My Little Pony for reference: [my-little-pony and friendship-is-magic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/4918)

**Update:** per the discussion below, I revoke the above request.  Instead, I will add the [my-little-pony] tag to all these questions, and everyone should try to make sure that the tag is added to questions in the future.  I'm not happy with this, because now we have two almost redundant tags we have to maintain.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a MLP ~> MLP-film tag synonym: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: @alexwlchan: No, I don't want a tag synonym.  Someone may want to ask a question about previous My Little Pony generations.  Although it's not very likely, such a question would be on-topic, so we should allow asking that, which is why we need an empty tag called "my-little-pony" for that.

Comment: So why not keep the MLP tag, in case such questions get asked? That way all MLP questions are together, whether from the film or not.

Comment: @alexwlchan: 1. tv series vs. film vs. comics vs. toys doesn't matter, [my-little-pony-fim] would probably apply to any of those.  (We might have an extra tag for the Equestria Girls film and its sequel specifically.)  These tags depend on whether the question is about the canon before or after the Friendship is Magic reboot.

Comment: @alexwlchan As for why not keep [my-little-pony] on everything: the problem is that currently if someone searches for [my-little-pony], he will miss 6 questions that aren't tagged there, and may ask a duplicate question.  If you could ensure that everything tagged with [my-little-pony-fim] gets tagged with [my-little-pony] as well, in the past and future, then we could keep both tags as far as I'm concerned (unless it gets impractical because of the 5 tag per question limit).

Answer (score 6):

If the argument against destroying the [my-little-pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony) is that there may be legitimate uses for the tag that don't involve [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim), then the solution is **not** to remove [my-little-pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony) from the 24 questions tagged with both it and [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim).

Instead, it should be added to the 7 [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim) questions currently missing it.

If we do have future questions that are legitimately about My Little Pony, but not about Friendship is Magic, then it becomes even more important that *all* My Little Pony questions, including the Friendship is Magic series, share a common set of tags.

Your concern is that someone searching for [my-little-pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony) instead of [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim) would miss 7 Friendship is Magic questions.  If we did as you're proposing, that someone searching would miss **all** Friendship is Magic questions.

If someone were looking to find *only* the non-Friendship is Magic questions, they could search on "[my-little-pony] -[my-little-pony-fim]" and get all the questions tagged with the first, but not the second.

Comment: Ok.  Suppose we add the [my-little-pony] tag to those 7 questions.  Do we then have a technological solution to make sure that the tag will be automatically added to all future questions posted under [my-little-pony-fim]?  If so, then I'm fine with just adding those tags.

Comment: @b_jonas Yes.  It is called peer review.  It is the same technological solution that we use to make sure that all [tag:hogwarts] questions also have [tag:harry-potter], all [tag:yoda] questions also have [tag:star-wars], all [tag:a-song-of-ice-and-fire] questions are also tagged [tag:george-r-r-martin], etc..  It isn't a perfect system, but it works, if people put the time in to edit.  Note that you have sufficient reputation to have simply added the 7 missing tags when you noticed them.

Comment: Ok. In that case I'll add those tags now.  I know I have the reputation to retag, but that also touches those questions to the list of active questions as an inconvenient side effect, so I didn't want to do it unless it's the right solution.  I might try to ask the SE folks for an automated technological solution as a longer term measure, for I'd seen this problem with other tags too, but I don't have my hopes high because of the 5 tag per page limit.

Comment: @b_jonas Bumping the questions is a valid issue.  I suggest doing no more than 2-3 at a time, and fairly widely spacing the others.  Incidentally, [I just posted this meta request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237284/166646) because I think there is potential value in reopening the idea of linking tags (it was rejected previously).

Comment: Too late about the bumping, sorry.

Comment: @b_jonas I doubt they're gonna make a technological solution.  This has been an issue forever on Stack Overflow, where there's a sort of tag hierarchy for many things: {programming language}-> {language version}-> {feature of said language}  People are just expected to tag properly, and the community fixes mistagged items.

Comment: Here we have franchise tags like [tag:star-wars], [tag:harry-potter], [tag:star-trek], etc.  [tag:my-little-pony] is just another one.  At the moment there's been no non FiM activity, but at some point there will be.

Comment: @Keen: I predict that there will be very little activity about pre-FiM My Little Pony, and most of that little will be motivated by FiM, especially about characters partly based on characters from a pre-reboot universe, such as Lord Tirek.  However, if I'm wrong, I don't want to discourage questions about pre-reboot My Little Pony.