# Delete tag [jk-rowling] (different from my previous request)

Tags: support, tags

I propose to delete [jk-rowling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk-rowling), and not recreate it.

This tag is currently used on approximately 30 questions.  All but two of those are also tagged [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter).  The two remaining questions should be tagged with [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) too, because they ask about Rowling writing Harry Potter, even if they don't mention it explicitly.

Rowling had specifically said that her future writings outside the Harry Potter universe are unlikely to be in the fantasy genre.  Her latest book, Casual Vacancy, is decidedly not in the fantasy genre.  Thus, it is quite likely that this tag won't be necessary in the future either.  This, and the fact that about 10% of our questions are related to Harry Potter makes my question different from my previous question [Remove tag [my-little-pony]](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4856/4918) .

Comment: I'd happily support you removing it from all but those questions that specifically relate to JKR the author, rather than her works of fiction

Answer (score 8):

**It shouldn’t be deleted.**

I think a lot of the questions tagged with [jk-rowling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk-rowling) don’t really need it, but I also think there are enough good questions where we really do need that tag to mark them as distinct from the other [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) questions. Here are some examples:

- [Does J.K. Rowling deny writing fantasy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2989/3567)
- [Did J. K. Rowling's Religious Beliefs Determine Much in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9133/3567)
- [Does Rowling have an inordinate fondness for the letter H in naming characters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10736/3567)
- [Is there any confirmed instance of J.K.Rowling changing her mind about future HP book detail to accomodate fans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7451/3567)
- [Was J.K. Rowling ever incorrect/misleading in her interviews/answers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10486/3567)

I think it’s a frequently misused tag, but I don’t think it should be deleted.

Comment: You seem to believe this tag serves a good purpose, and that purpose is not just marking any question related to works of Rowling.  If that is the case, can you try to phrase what this purpose is and what kind of questions should get that tag?  If you succeed, edit the tag wiki.

Comment: @b_jonas Something to do with J.K. Rowling’s comments on and/or discussion of the HP books, which can be distinct from discussion of the plot of the books. (Or something along those lines.)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4860/1359)

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing, was about the ask the question before I found this one. The jk-rowling tag seems to be being used in an inconsistent manner. I think the main distinction is that a jk-rowling question is usually an "out-of-universe" question, while many of the ones tagged are currently looking for in-universe explanations (even if these refer to JKR interviews). I was considering doing some clean-up and potentially writing the tag wiki, but wanted to check whether this was still the consensus? :)

Comment: @Luna Nobody has asked about it since, so this seems to be consensus. Two caveats: 1) Some users frown on people flooding the front page with edits; it's preferred to space out lots of edits. 2) That said, I had a quick look over the tag - it doesn't seem to me like there are many mistagged questions. We've been pretty good about tidying it up. :-)

Comment: @alexwlchan That's fair, thank you for replying. I'll just keep a look-out for it then, and perhaps try and think of a good wiki summary :)