# Let's figure out our Tolkien tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, we have a bunch of [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) tags:

- [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien)
- [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth)
- [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings)
- [the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit)
- [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion)
- [fellowship-of-the-ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fellowship-of-the-ring)
- [the-two-towers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-two-towers)
- [return-of-the-king](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-of-the-king)

(as mentioned by @JasonBaker:)

- [an-unexpected-journey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/an-unexpected-journey)
- [desolation-of-smaug](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desolation-of-smaug)
- [battle-of-five-armies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle-of-five-armies)

(These^ are for the movies, I think.)

**Do we need *all* of those tags?**

I can see keeping [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) and [the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit) separate. And even [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion) (though I would prefer it being renamed to [the-silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-silmarillion)).

But to we need the individual work tags? Questions may be from one book, but answers will often be from the entire canon.

As for [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth)... We need to either clarify usage or burninate it. As it is, it's being used on *some* [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) questions, because [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) is *almost* a synonym of [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien). Notice that I said *almost*. The difference is, that [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) can be used to refer to the *place*, not just the works that are set there (as I think that the usage should be).

Thoughts?

Comment: But having lots of Tolkien tags is why the [tag map](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9522) looks cool.

Comment: I need some Tolkiens for the arcade...

Comment: @Hack-R - Are you Tolkien 'bout my generation?

Comment: Individual works should all have their own unique tags, if the question is about them. That's our general policy, no reason to exclude Tolkien's works.

Comment: Aforementioned policy: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178

Comment: Followup posted: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10655/31394

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tolkien tags - the way forward](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10655/tolkien-tags-the-way-forward)

Answer (score 14):

Wearied as I am by tag tomfoolery, I suppose I do have a warg in this fight.

That being said, most of your complaints aren't actually directed at Tolkien tags; there are secretly two or three different [holy wars](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Holy%20War&defid=4683278) lurking beneath the surface.

- Obviously, there's little reason to get rid of [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings), [the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit), and [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion). Insofar as separate tags for the Tolkien Legendarium are necessary, those three unquestionably are
- I don't see any point in renaming to [the-silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-silmarillion), other than pedantry. I'm also not going to throw a tantrum if it does happen, but I'll point out that this isn't the only tag that should be renamed as such, if that's important to the community - it's not even the only tag in this discussion.
- The [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) tag is an interesting one because it's a rare case that one of the other tags wouldn't apply. I can perhaps imagine a situation where a question was asked about Tolkien himself ([Did Tolkien have experience with addiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47773/31051) would be one such example).

  Of course, we have an astonishing precedent for "author" tags on this site; off the top of my head, we also have [cs-lewis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs-lewis), [brandon-sanderson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brandon-sanderson), [george-lucas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-lucas), [jk-rowling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk-rowling), [giger](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/giger) (for some frigging reason), [gene-roddenberry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gene-roddenberry), [rod-duncan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rod-duncan). And I've no doubt there are more besides. This is Holy War Number One.

  There are really only two things a tag like this would be good for:

  1. The tag being for questions about Tolkien himself. This is essentially [alexwlchan's response to a similar discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4858/31051).
  2. A general tag for the Legendarium as a whole. The more I think about this, the more I think about how incredibly useful such a tag would be; it's quite rare that a question is ever truly restricted to a single book, and there seems to be a natural tendency towards creating this sort of tag; it's basically what [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) has turned into over the years, and many people try to use [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) for the same purpose. It's also, essentially, what [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars), [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) are, among many others.

     If we were being pedantic, something like [tolkien-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-legendarium) would be the best option for this purpose; since Tolkien did write things not set in his imagined world, it seems unfair to lump them all under his name.

  Realistically, though, there's little hope in changing course now; without developer intervention (I don't think mod intervention is sufficient), which seems unlikely given the complexity of the undertaking, modifying all 900+ [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) questions, and/or introducing a new tag for all 1000+ Legendarium questions, is going to take a prohibitively long time to do; we're trying to [stop a train with a BB gun](https://what-if.xkcd.com/18/). My philosophical inclination (and I admit [my bias](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/231/tolkien?userid=31051)) is just to leave the past in the past, and try to do better going forward
- The purpose of the "works" tags ([fellowship-of-the-ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fellowship-of-the-ring), [the-two-towers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-two-towers), [return-of-the-king](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-of-the-king)) is to be used for the films, not the books. This isn't something that is always done consistently, but it fits with the many, many *other* tags we have for individual films.

  That being said, I actually agree with you: there's little point in having them at all, and you can throw [an-unexpected-journey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/an-unexpected-journey), [desolation-of-smaug](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desolation-of-smaug), [battle-of-five-armies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle-of-five-armies), [star-trek-first-contact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-first-contact), [return-of-the-jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-of-the-jedi), and all the rest in with them. On several occasions I've started drafting a meta post on this very topic, before ultimately falling victim to the "couldn't be arsed" virus.

  This is (or shortly will be) Holy War Number Two.
- [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth). Fun fact: the usage of this tag [has *already* been clarified](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/middle-earth/info), way [back in 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5zWFBlc9N8):

  > ### FAQ
  >
  > #### Q. Isn't everything in Tolkien's Legendarium part of Middle-earth?
  >
  > **A.** No: Middle-earth is one small section of the world Tolkien created, Arda. Other regions include Beleriand, north of Middle-earth and the original home of the Elves; Númenor, the land of the Dúnedain; Aman, the undying lands of the Valar and the elves; and the Dark Lands, south of Middle-earth.
  >
  > #### Q. When should I tag something Middle-earth?
  >
  > **A.** Use [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) when you want to ask a question about something general to Middle-earth: a location, a race, or a historical event. You can use it in conjunction with other, more specific tags like [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) or [the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit). Do not use it when you want to refer to other parts of Arda, like most of the events of *The Silmarillion*.

  That being said, this tag is fantastically frequently misused. Just looking at the ten [most recent questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) in the tag, I'd say that **nine** of them don't need it; [Was Beleriand Bigger than Second/Third Age Middle-earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135204/31051) is the lone exception.

  Obviously that's not to say that it should *never* be used, but it needs to be policed far more effectively than it currently has been.

And guess what! There are *so many more* "Tolkien" tags that you haven't even considered:

- [shadow-of-mordor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-mordor) should be left
- [sauron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sauron), [gandalf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gandalf), [saruman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saruman), <s>[aragorn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aragorn)</s>, <s>[bilbo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bilbo)</s>, [morgoth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morgoth), <s>[feanor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feanor)</s>, [galadriel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galadriel), <s>[melian](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melian)</s>, <s>[hurin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hurin)</s>, [smaug](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smaug), [tom-bombadil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-bombadil), <s>[earendil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earendil)</s>, <s>[luthien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luthien)</s>, [gollum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gollum). I'm sure there are more, but this is starting to depress me.

  All of these fall under the general umbrella of "[character tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6839/31051)", which have a contentious history on this site. Personally, I think they should all be cast into the Void with the Great Enemy, where they belong. Some of these I just [executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ragmt.jpg).

  This is Holy War Number Three

  - Subcategory: [arkenstone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkenstone). I want to kill it, but it's marginally useful.
  - Another subcategory: [smeagol](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smeagol) was rrecently (ish) aliased with [gollum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gollum). This is *probably* for the best, although I contend that they're different characters. But then I hate character tags, so I'm not going to complain about reducing their numbers
- [valar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valar), [istari](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/istari), [maiar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maiar), [nazgul](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazgul), [hobbits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hobbits), [ents](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ents), [edain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edain) are more forgivable than character tags, because they encompass relatively-broad subcategories of the Legendarium, and yet have narrowly-defined scopes
- [numenor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numenor), [undying-lands](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undying-lands), [bree](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bree) and [arda](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arda) make as much sense as [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) (though personally I think [bree](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bree) should be subsumed by [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth), and then removed from all questions that aren't actually about Bree; which is *all* of them)
- [the-one-ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring), [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power), [mithril](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mithril) make a certain amount of sense, and are well-scoped.

  - As an aside, I think there's sufficient reason to keep [the-one-ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring) separate from [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power)
- [elves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elves), [dwarves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarves), [orc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orc) are weird cases, because they're *mostly* used on Tolkien questions, and yet also refer to common fantasy elements. They're *probably* fine to leave as-is
- [tolkien-languages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-languages) makes sense to leave
- [christopher-tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christopher-tolkien) makes as much sense as [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) does, as long as we restrict it in the same way; some questions would need clean-up

Comment: Re [tag:tolkien-languages], see [this meta post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9282/31394).

Comment: Actually, [screw it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nTVbK.gif). I'm just going to kill all of those character tags that are only on, like, 5 questions

Comment: [tag:undying-lands], [tag:numenor], [tag:arkenstone]... etc.

Comment: @amaranth [*sigh*](https://media.giphy.com/media/M9o2jL3ZRB09a/giphy.gif)

Comment: Just look for green in the bottom right of the [tag map](http://yellowantphil.com/tags/scifi.html).

Comment: So they're all OK now except bree?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Ehhhh; maybe. Depends on how pedantic you want to be. Personally I think the installment tags have room for cleanup, but there should be a discussion around that before we actually move. And of course I still want to take all the character tags behind the shed, but that's another holy war that's never been fully resolved. I *am* inclined to do some cleanup of middle-earth, though, but that's the only one I feel comfortable acting on at this point

Comment: re: author tags - this is a direct consequence of a disastrous design decision by SE to not implement tag hierarchies. Ideally, alll tolkien-content tags would hierarchically fold into [tag:tolkien] and thus make the latter higher level tag un-needed on ALL questions except those specifically pertaining to Tolkien himself.

Comment: FWIW, i happen to agree that per-film tags for small series are largely useless, especially if they are intelligently aliased .

Comment: `My philosophical inclination (and I admit my bias) is just to leave the past in the past, and try to do better going forward` yes this, but no to the "little point" in individual work tags, unless specifically you roll all the Hobbit trilogy tags into a hobbit-trilogy tag.

Comment: @CreationEdge Part of the problem is that they're very inconsistent; we don't, for instance, have individual tags for each Harry Potter book (or film). Another part of the problem is that it's not clear when they should be used; if I ask a question about one film, I guess I should put that tag on it, but what if I'm asking a general question about the franchise? Should I put every installment tag on it (which I generally can't do anyway - another problem)? Why/why not? What problem are they trying to solve?

Comment: The current policy is to tag the individual work *and* franchise, always. So, there should be a franchise tag, too. Harry Potter is our biggest offender, because it unfortunately was too huge before anyone noticed (or cared) that how we were tagging it was awful. It's one of those "try to do better going forward" things (which can can specifically do with Fantastic Beasts!). If you look at other tags, like Marvel/DC universe stuff, we're very consistent there. Even Star Trek does a good job of getting individual works in there (eg, each of the 3 Abram's movies have tags)

Comment: Anyway, I think some leeway for certain works could be allowed. Very closed trilogies, such as the Hobbit trilogy, for example, could make sense all having a single `hobbit-trilogy` tag, since they're essentially meant to be 3 parts to the same story, and it's probably rare a question that won't have answers possibly involving all 3. We do this with `the-matrix` and I see no problems there.

Comment: @CreationEdge I find your second comment broadly applicable to all multi-part series; Star Wars, Star Trek, Harry Potter, and Tolkien being the ones I'm most familiar with. The only problem these tags are good at solving is defining the scope of the question, but that rarely seems like a useful thing to do

Comment: Perhaps, but some films are much more stand-alone than the others. The Abram's ST trilogy, for instance. Each of those movies could be watched independently without a problem, because they have self-contained narratives, and *many* of the questions tagged as such are really just about a single film, not the series. The LotR/Hobbit films, otoh, are generally more generic about the franchise or trilogy, and I agree that the individual tags aren't helpful.

Comment: How are you liking the new cleaned-up Tolkien tagging system? :-)

Comment: "*The purpose of the "works" tags (fellowship-of-the-ring, the-two-towers, return-of-the-king) is to be used for the films, not the books.*" - why on earth? That would be really confusing, since the canon called by those names is the books. It's also not what the tag wikis say for those tags.

Answer (score 0):

### Leave 'em.

As per my [stock objection](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10008/20774) to tag removal.

- As things stand, these tags are pretty harmless and possibly of minor use to anyone with a passing interest in specific elements of Tolkien-related works
- Mucking around with these tags *on a systematic basis* will result in the front page being disfigured with worthless edits for (at minimum) several weeks.
- **As usual, I see no justification given to explain why messing around with these tags is of *more benefit* to the site than simply leaving them in situ.**

Comment: But.. but.. my OCD! How can I go on without knowing that I've lessened the choices in the world?!